# Al guardar en base de datos un campo de tipo date, este se guarda con fecha de un día anterior

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring, hibernate

Estoy programando una aplicación con las siguientes tecnologías:

- Java, Spring, Hibernate, Maven, Msql.

El IDE que estoy utilizando es Eclipse.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que al momento de persistir una entidad, una de sus propiedades, es de tipo Date, este se registra con una valor de un día anterior al indicado.

Ejemplo:

Se desea registrar 11-10-18 y registra : 10-10-18.

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar tu código para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte con mayor facilidad?

Answer (score 0):

Debe estar por defecto en un horario GTM, tu puedes agregar o configurar la fecha que ingresa usando esta anotación:

```
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", locale = "en_GB")
```

puedes cambiar el locale depende donde estes.